# Using ShareActionProvider on a CardView in a Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-intent, shareactionprovider

I am trying to provide a share feature on the cards displayed in my android application. I have learn't about the ShareactionProvider. This actionProvider is suppose to be present on every cardview. I have placed the code for the ShareActionprovider on my onBindViewHolder in the Adapter. When the app starts, all the cards execute their share at the same time. I will like to call this share only when the user requests.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final Cursor cursor) {
final NewsFacade facade = NewsFacade.fromCursor(cursor);
MenuItem shareMenuItem = viewHolder.toolbar.getMenu().findItem(R.id.share);
    ShareActionProvider shareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(shareMenuItem);
    shareActionProvider.setShareIntent(viewHolder.sendShareIntent(facade, context));
    shareActionProvider.setShareHistoryFileName("custom_share_history.xml");
```

And Here are the Helper Methods to aid in the sharing:

```
public Intent sendShareIntent(NewsFacade facade, Context context)
    {
        saveImageToCache(facade, context);
       return shareImage(context);
    }

    private void saveImageToCache(NewsFacade facade, Context context)
    {
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = facade.getThumb();
            File cachePath = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "images");
            cachePath.mkdirs(); 
            FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(cachePath + "/image.png"); // overwrites this image every time
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            stream.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Intent shareImage(Context context)
    {
        File imagePath = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "images");
        File newFile = new File(imagePath, "image.png");
        Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.example.clinton.companion.fileprovider", newFile);

        if (contentUri != null) {

            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); // temp permission for receiving app to read this file
            shareIntent.setDataAndType(contentUri,context.getContentResolver().getType(contentUri));
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Choose an app"));
            return shareIntent;

        }
        return null;
    }
```

I know, I am calling the ActionProvider in the wrong place. But where else, should I call this, I need an instance of the object that cardview holds, so I can get the image in the cardview to share.

Please any help will be apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. 
I was calling

```
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Choose an app"));
```

which automatically executes the sharing.